# Unable to make a JMS connection server hosted in another machine

Tags: jms

We are using JMS with JBoss 5.1.0.GA.

I can send JMS messages to JBoss when it's hosted on the same machine as my producer, but when I host JBoss in other machine then I am getting below issue:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server /M2:1099
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:335)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1734)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server /M2:1099
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:305)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @JustinBertram JNDI name: ConnectionFactory,  broker: ip_address_m2:1099,  Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY= "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory", Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces

Comment: @JustinBertram JBoss 5.1.0.GA...[org.jboss.web.WebService] (main) Using RMI server codebase: http:// ip_address_m2:8083/
[org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
[org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) 3.1.2.GA
[org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AttributeCallbackItem] (main) Owner callback not implemented.
[org.jboss.logbridge.LogNotificationListener] (main) Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@4bbda190[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]

Comment: That's just a small snippet of the start-up logs. Can modify your question to include the logs from the full start-up process?

Comment: @JustinBertram can you tell me the configuration file of JBoss where i need to look up?

Comment: @JustinBertram i am not asking about logs file location..i am asking about any xml file where we can bind jboss to a public network interface so that it can be reached from a remote client.

Comment: @JustinBertram So the bind address can be specified only through the command line...isn't there any configuration file where we can specify the bind address??

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like JBoss isn't binding to a public network interface so that it can be reached from a remote client.

JBoss has many different services (e.g. JMS, JNDI, EJB, HTTP) which each use the configured bind address but bind to different ports. Each of these can be configured individually or they can be configured globally.

The simplest way to configure the bind address globally is to use the `-b` command-line switch. Simply start the broker using the `-b` switch, e.g. `./run.sh -b 127.0.0.1`. Of course you'd want to replace `127.0.0.1` with a remotely accessible IP address or hostname.

If you don't want to do that then you can modify the file `bin/run.conf`. Just add `-Djboss.bind.address=<myBindAddress>` to the `JAVA_OPTS` variable.